# Why $\|U^*AU\|=\|A\|?$ with $U$ unitary operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> Let $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ and $U$ be any unitary operator in $E$. Why
>   $$\|U^*AU\|=\|A\|?$$

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the definition of the operator norm and of a unitary operator? If not you should look them up.

Comment: $\frac{\langle x, U^* A U x \rangle}{\langle x , x \rangle} =  \frac{\langle U x,  A U x \rangle}{\langle U x , U x \rangle}$

Comment: For all $x\in E$ you have that $\left\|U^*AUx\right\|^2=(U^*AUx,U^*AUx)=(UU^*AUx,AUx)=(AUx,AUx)=\left\|AUx\right\|^2$. Since $U$ is invertible, $Ux$ are all $y\in E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S=\{x : \|x\| = 1\}$. $U$ defines a bijection in $S$.

In particular, $y=Ux \iff x=U^*y$.

Therefore:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\|U^*AU\|
&=& \displaystyle \sup_{x \in S} \|U^*AUx\| \\
&=& \displaystyle \sup_{x \in S} \|AUx\| \\
&=& \displaystyle \sup_{x \in S} \|Ay\| \\
&=& \displaystyle \sup_{y \in S} \|Ay\| \\
&=& \|A\|
\end{array}$$